# link mui v6 datagrid edit fields

Tags: mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

I have a MUI v6 datagrid with row edit mode enabled. When I edit the start time or end time values I want the worked time to be updated as well so that it is in the edited row data. Ideally this should happen as the user types so they get visual feedback regarding the time worked.

My current datagrid code:

```
<DataGrid
          {...StyledDataGridProps}
          columns={dgColumns}
          rows={dgRows}
          autoHeight
          editMode="row"
          rowModesModel={rowModesModel}
          onRowEditStart={handleRowEditStart}
          onRowEditStop={handleRowEditStop}
          processRowUpdate={processRowUpdate}
        />
```